# Update assembly version with MSBUILD command

Tags: c#, msbuild, target, assemblyinfo

I'm running the following command

`msbuild Project.csproj /p:Configuration="Release" /p:VersionAssembly=0.0.0.7 /p:Version=0.0.0.7 /p:VersionSuffix=0.0.0.7 /p:BuildProjectReferences=false`

To update the File version is there a way to do it without the AssemblyInfo target task in the project I would like to avoid update the project.

Comment: you'd have to write that out manually

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Preferably use the project file instead of an AssemblyInfo file for versioning.

Comment: @PMF I'm using NET48, I created an MSBuild task  in external file.proj to build https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022  but the target needs to be specify in the csproj file. Do you know a way to add a task  without to updated the project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You don't want to change the csproj file? Why?